# The maximum number of form, query string, or posted file error in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

While populating more than thousands of products, I am getting below error in asp.net

> The maximum number of form, query string, or posted file items has
>   already been read from the request. To change the maximum allowed
>   request collection count from its current value of 1000, change the
>   "aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" setting. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238386 for more information.

I tried changing code in web.config also with `<appsetting>` and set `maxhttpcollectionkeys` as 5000 also but still getting above error.

Please suggest solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Is 5000 high enough? Did you try more? Did you try changing your design so you do not end up posting that much data in a single request?

Comment: Do you have `HiddenField`s ? If so, try to reduce them or replace them by something which not involve form controls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to further increase the size until it is satisfactory, but watch out for the security of your application, as the increase in this key may actually increase the vulnerability of your server.
A good tip would be to revise its number of controls on the page.